# How to reset the colorscheme to default in vi editor?

Tags: linux, unix, vim

How to set the `colorscheme` to default permanently in vi editor?

Comment: this link https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1565/Enabling+vi+syntax+colors#gs may help you

Comment: In .vimrc file using this way for execution mode :colorscheme default

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put `colorscheme ..` line into `~/.vimrc` file:

```
echo "colorscheme default" >> ~/.vimrc
```

Comment: I do not have this .vimrc file. Should I create this file?

Comment: @falsetrue Thanks man.. It is working fine. May I know why the colorscheme is changed to some other scheme? My account is newly created one. Nothing inside. How come the colorschme was changed from default?

Comment: @Nadaraj, Maybe it could be in the shared vimrc file like: `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` (or another file that is `source`d by the shared vimrc)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference OP, here is the wiki page for it (Since falsetru has already answered the question)

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switch_color_schemes